# rotation reverse using tween max

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, gsap

so brief about me - I am a newbie to animations and javascript/jquery.

I have created a ferris with the following html

```
<div class="ferris-wrapper">
  <div class="ferris-stand"></div>
  <div id="ferris-wheel"></div>
</div>
```

I was playing around with tweenmax and was able to rotate the ferris-wheel

```
var ferris = document.getElementById("ferris-wheel");
TweenLite.from(ferris, 0, { rotation:0, ease:Linear.easeNone } );
TweenLite.to(ferris, 10, { rotation:360, ease:Linear.easeNone } );
```

My question is -

After the ferris wheel rotates 360 degrees. How can I make it reverse 360 degrees the other way?
Also, I want this to loop infinitely.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know anything about TweenLite but did you simply tried `TweenLite.to(ferris, 10, { rotation:-360, ease:Linear.easeNone } );` ?

Comment: i made it loop by adding repeat:-1

Comment: but adding an extra tweenlite to doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `yoyo:true` and `repeat:-1` to your tween

```
var ferris = document.getElementById("ferris-wheel");
TweenMax.from(ferris, 0, { rotation:0, yoyo:true, repeat:-1, ease:Linear.easeNone } );
TweenMax.to(ferris, 10, { rotation:360, yoyo:true, repeat:-1, ease:Linear.easeNone } );
```

You will have to use [TweenMax](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/) to use `yoyo`

> yoyo : Boolean - If true, every other repeat cycle will run in the opposite direction so that the tween appears to go back and forth (forward then backward). This has no affect on the "reversed" property though. So if repeat is 2 and yoyo isfalse, it will look like: start - 1 - 2 - 3 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 1 - 2 - 3 - end. But if yoyo is true, it will look like: start - 1 - 2 - 3 - 3 - 2 - 1 - 1 - 2 - 3 - end.

`yoyo:true` causes the tween to go back and forth, alternating backward and forward on each repeat.

`repeat:-1` makes your animation loop forever

Reference: http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/

Also here is a cool Ferris Wheel animation by [GreenSock](http://greensock.com) on codepen:

http://codepen.io/GreenSock/details/wBbKs

Hope this helps!